# Orthogonality on a circle

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

These theory questions always throw me for a loop.

Ok, the question is:

Suppose that AB is the diameter of the circle with center O and that C is a point on one of the two arcs joining A and B. Show that $\vec{CA}$ and $\vec{CB}$ are orthogonal.

I know I'm suppose to use the dot product somewhere in this, but I don't know how to write this out as a proof.

[image: picture of circle]

Comment: Hint. Euclid knew this, without linear algebra and dot products. Search "angle inscribed in a semicircle". If you're required to produce a proof using linear algebra I'm sure one will appear here soon.

Comment: $(\vec{c} + \vec{u}) \cdot (\vec{c} - \vec{u}) = \vec{c}\cdot\vec{c} - \vec{u}\cdot\vec{u} = |\vec{c}|^2 - |\vec{u}|^2 = ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have $u \cdot u = v \cdot v = r^2$ and  $$\vec{AC} = \vec{AO} + \vec{OC} = u+v, \quad \vec{BC} = \vec{BO} + \vec{OC} = v - u,   $$ we will take the dot product  $$ \vec{AC}\cdot \vec{BC} = (v+u)\cdot (v-u) =v.v-u.u = r^2 - r^2 = 0. $$  therefore $$AC  \text{ and } BC \text{ are orthogonal. }$$

Comment: thanks man, this makes sense. I just have a hard time thinking it out with just all variables.

Comment: @lasec0203, you are welcome.